# How do you beat the boss in Keyboard Drumset Fucking Werewolf?

Tags: kdfw

How do you beat the boss in Keyboard Drumset Fucking Werewolf? I noticed two spots you can hit, his lower like organ and his upper unicorn head. I've never killed the unicorn head, but I am able to hit that lower organ.

To beat it, do I just beat both the head and organ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it will bite it as long as you take the head down.  This guy seems to be doing pretty well by avoiding attacks and focusing on firing upwards at the unicorn head:

Comment: Just a tip, I was bashing the shoot button when I was unable to beat this. But I find if you get a weapon that you can hold down the shoot button, you can win very easily

Comment: Or perhaps you could hack together some type of rapid fire using a controller or keyboard macro program?  Just a thought...

Comment: That's true. I actually wrote a C# script for a game before:

`using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Turbkey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            while(true)
                SendKeys.SendWait("z");
        }
    }
}`

Can't believe I forgot about that! Gotta use this more often lol